# Chef powershell function

Tags: function, powershell, chef-infra

I am very new to Chef and to Powershell, so I hope this makes sense. I need to make add servers (Chef nodes) to a domain, and Powershell seems to be the way to go. I have found a function that I have modified a little so that I can do this in an idempotent way.

My problem is I am not sure how to put this in a Chef recipe.

I have looked around but without luck, and most Chef examples I find are very simple (install IIS or tomcat type) cookbooks. I am including the "recipe" I am trying to create here:

```sh
#
# set this up for reboot should we join domain successfully 
#
windows_reboot 5 do
  reason 'Reboot after joining AD'
  action :nothing
end

# 
# import mixin powershellout here
# also, make sure that Powershell cookbook is on active runlist for node
#
::Chef::Recipe.send(:include, Chef::Mixin::PowershellOut)

powershell_script "addToDomain" do

########################################################################################  
# put the powershell script in here between the ruby heredoc string thingies
# ref: http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/syntax.html#here_doc
#
script =<<-'EOF'
  $exitVal=0;
  function addComputer { param([string]$username, [string]$password, [string]$domain)
   try {
      if ((gwmi win32_computersystem).partofdomain -eq $true) {
          # arguably here, I would check if it is the RIGHT domain... next rev...
          $oldDomain = [System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain]::GetCurrentDomain()
          $domainName = $oldDomain.name
          if($domain -eq $oldDomain)
          {
            $message = \"The system is joined to the domain\";
            $exitVal=2;
          }
          else
          {
            Remove-Computer -UnjoinDomainCredential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force))) -Force -PassThru -verbose 
            $message = \"computer leaved domain\";
            $exitVal=4;
          }
      }
      else {
          add-computer -domain $domain -credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, (ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force))) -passthru -verbose
          $message = \"computer joined to domain\";
          $exitVal=3;
      }
   }
   catch
   {
    $message = \"Join Error - \";
    $message += $_;
    $exitVal=1;
   }
   write-host $message;
   exit $exitVal;
}
# this next line uses ruby 
addComputer #{node['ad']['user']} #{node['ad']['pwd']} #{node['ad']['domain']}
EOF
########################################################################################
#
#
result = powershell_out(script)

Chef::Log.debug("powershell exit #{result.exitstatus}")
Chef::Log.debug("powershell error #{result.stderr}")
Chef::Log.debug("powershell stdout #{result.stdout}")

# same as shell_out
if result.exitstatus == 2
  Chef::Log.debug("Already part of domain: #{result.stdout}")
elsif result.exitstatus == 3 or result.exitstatus == 4
  Chef::Log.debug("Joined domain: #{result.stdout}")
  # reboot if joining or leaving domain
  notifies :request, 'windows_reboot[5]', :delayed
else
  Chef::Log.error("Domain join fail: #{result.stdout}")
  # any other actions here?  maybe flag the node?
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that your Powershell approach is not the simplest way to achieve this.  There are cookbooks out there that can do this for you - have a look at the [window_ad cookbook](https://github.com/TAMUArch/cookbook.windows_ad), which looks to me like it will do what you want.  Note that you'll need to use the LWRP part of it, not the default recipe.

Comment: Thank you, I had previously seen that cookbook, but since the description says it installs AD in a server, I didn't think it was what I needed. I realize now that it can also be used to join a domain.

Comment: You're welcome - quite a few cookbooks seem to include LWRP features as an afterthought - not sure why!